# Modifying javascript to output form name instead of form id

Tags: php, javascript, forms, dynamic

I made several input field boxes with the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.add').click(function(){
            par_id=$(this).parent().attr('id');
            count=$("#"+par_id+"> input").length;
            id=par_id.toString();
            $(this).parent().append("<br/><input type='text' id='"+id+"'>");
        });
    });//]]>  
</script>
```

I'm using the aforementioned code in order to create input fields that can dynamically add new fields.

This code creates multiple identical form ids, but I want it to create multiple identical form names so I can output it altogether using the foreach command.

Now I want to output the input data into a PHP using this

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST['formid'] as $value) {
        echo "$value <br />";
    }
?>
```

What I want to ask is that the foreach command will only output data from the **form name**, but the javascript code I am using creates more input forms by the **form id**, not the form name.

So I need a code that will create more input boxes with **form name**, not form id!

I'm not sure how to modify the original code, since I got it from another website.

Please help!

Comment: The JS code is currently manipulating DOM and creating multiple elements with same id which is not valid. If you can update your post with what you are trying to achieve, may be a better approach can be usgessted

Comment: Thanks Chandu for the quick response! I do want to create multiple forms, just with the same 'name' so I can output it using the foreach command.

Comment: Just send the forms to the server in an array with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or use AJAX altogether to submit.

Comment: @elclanrs - OP's statement in the question that _"I'm not sure how to modify the original code, since I got it from another website."_ and the question in general, suggests that OP is not as technically skilled as a consumer of your suggestion might need to be. As such, a more elaborate comment might help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add a name attribute to the code which is inserted by the javascript function.

Original:

```
$(this).parent().append("<br/><input type='text' id='"+id+"'>");
```

Ammended:

```
$(this).parent().append("<br/><input type='text' name='yourinputname' id='"+id+"'>");
```

EDIT: Just and afterthought...

If the ID serves no purpose and only the name attribute is required, the majority of this code is unnecessary and can be reduced to the following.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('.add').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().append("<br/><input type='text' name='yourinputname');
        });
    });//]]>  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chung - I have tried to understand your question and have come up with the suggestions below, but you have to understand that your question is quite vague, confusing and possibly misleading.

**Making minimal changes to your code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.add').click(function() {
        par_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        par_name = $(this).parent().attr('name');
        count = $("#" + par_id + "> input").length;
        id = par_id.toString();
        $(this).parent().append("<br/><input type='text' name='" + par_name + "' id='" + id + "'>");
    });
});​
```

**As demoed here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/2nV3m/

**Some doubts/suggestions:**

- Why is there a `count` when you are not using it? `par_id` is always a string, but you are casting it to `string`, which suggests that you possibly were expecting the `count` in there somewhere?
- In my suggested state, the `form` contains multiple `input`s with the same `name`, as such, you will not be able to iterate over it using `foreach`, instead you will receive the `value`s of all those elements as a `comma-delimited` list.
- Are you then possibly wanting to name each element differently using the `count` and then loop at server-side using `for` instead of `foreach`? As demoed here: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/7pK29/

Comment: Thanks so much bPratik for your incredibly informative response! Unfortunately I'm not sure how to answer your questions even, because I do not know the exact functions of the code I'm using. Which to say is quite silly, I'm sorry! I just wanted to have a javascript code that will give me multiple text input boxes that I can output to a PHP, but all of the codes I could find on the internet will not let me make different multiple boxes with different form names (so I can output more than one of these multiple boxes on the same php). Perhaps I am using a totally incorrect approach..?

Comment: `the form contains multiple inputs with the same name...you will not be able to iterate over it using foreach` is not correct. Form controls are made named properties of the form they are in. If multiple elements have the same name, then `form.controlName` returns a collection of same–named controls that can be iterated over (using some version of `forEach` or a typical `for`, `while` or `do` loop).

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment:

```
> par_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

The variable `par_id` should be kept local so declare it. The expression is simpler, more efficient and less to type as:

```
var par_id = this.parentNode.id;
```

regarding:

```
> count=$("#"+par_id+"> input").length;
```

As pointed out in other answers, the count variable is not used (and should be declared so it stays local). Since you want to use the element with id `par_id` more than once, consider:

```
var par_el = this.parentNode;
var par_id = par_el.id;
var count = $(par_el).find('input').length;
```

Using property access where available is much simpler and more efficient that calling functions to do the same thing.